# Как перенести фамилию Басилашвили?

Tags: перенос

Как перенести фамилию Басилашвили? Ба-си-ла-швили или Ба-си-лаш-вили

Comment: "Швили" часто в грузинских фамилиях, поэтому лучше "шв" не делить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- По школьным правилам можно переносить и так, и сяк. Там допускается
  вариативность.
- Если следовать углублённой программе, то переносить следует так:
  *...ла-шви...* (по правилу, что глухие согласные отходят к следующему слогу).
- Если следовать филфаковскому закону восходящей звучности, то переносить тоже надо так: *...ла-шви...* (конец слога должен быть с максимальной звучностью, в вашем случае это гласная).